# MySQL - Cloning then changing a field - Is this a race condition?

Tags: mysql

While debugging an issue in our software system, I came across a prepared statement that looks something like this:

```
"UPDATE Command SET expiredWhen=status, status='expired' WHERE id=?;"
```

The `expiredWhen` field is supposed to be set to whatever value is in the `status` field, then the `status` field is supposed to be set to "expired". It worked as expected in our MySQL 5.1 environment, but in MySQL 5.5 `expiredWhen` is being set to "expired".

What is the expected result of this statement? Is this a race condition, and we were lucky that it ever worked? Or is there defined behavior for this statement that changed from version 5.1 to 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) is consistent between versions 5.1 and 5.5:

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to
>   right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that
>   assignments are carried out in any particular order

This suggests that it *shouldn't* be a race condition.  That said, the word "generally" is a little concerning - it would probably be safest to assume that it *could* be a race condition.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that when looking for this answer in the docs. That "generally" doesn't fill me with confidence... I think I'll just break this up in to two statements. Still, I'm curious as to why it stopped working